# Is it danger cast int * to unsigned int *

Tags: c++

I have variable of type int *alen. Trying to pass it to function:

```
typedef int(__stdcall *Tfnc)(
    unsigned int *alen
    );
```

with casting

```
(*Tfnc)( (unsigned int *)alen )
```

Can I expect problems in case value is never negative?

Comment: If the value is never negative why are you not using `unsigned` in the first place

Comment: If the value can never be negative anyway, why not use `unsigned int` throughout? Besides giving some better type-safety it will also be easier to read and understand and maintain, as well as give you bigger range.

Comment: Just use assert() and you won't have to be sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Under the C++ standard, what you are doing is undefined behavior.  The memory layout of unsigned and signed ints is not guaranteed to be compatible, as far as I know.

On most platforms (which use 2s complement integers), this will not be a problem.

The remaining issue is strict aliasing, where the compiler is free to presume that pointers to one type and pointers to another type are not pointers to the same thing.

```
typedef int(__stdcall *Tfnc)(
  unsigned int *alen
);

int test() {
  int x = 3;
  Tfnc pf = [](unsigned int* bob) { *bob = 2; };
  pf((unsigned int*)&x);
  return x;
}
```

the above code *might* be allowed to ignore the modification to the `x` while it is modified through the `unsigned int*`, even on 2s complement hardware.

That is the price of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

No it won't be of any problem, until and unless the int value you pass is not negative.
But if the given value is negative then the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2^n where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type).